# When and How android initializes SIM card info

Tags: android, boot, sim-card

I would like to know two things regarding to Android SIM initialization process:

1. Which Service is responsible to retrieve SIM card information?
2. When the Android framework retrieve that information at runtime / on reboot?

Answer (score 1):

> How android initializes SIM card?

This is done by the [TelephonyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) and its different [getSimSerialNumber()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimSerialNumber()) (Also see other [getSim*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimCountryIso()) methods).

> When android initializes SIM card?

This is happend a lot inside framework (You can see [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/search?q=getSimSerialNumber&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&project=abi&project=art&project=bionic&project=bootable&project=build&project=cts&project=dalvik&project=developers&project=development&project=device&project=docs&project=external&project=frameworks&project=hardware&project=libcore&project=libnativehelper&project=ndk&project=packages&project=pdk&project=platform_testing&project=prebuilts&project=sdk&project=system&project=tools) any time this method is being called), But in general any time the phone is reboot or the phone come back from `Flight State`.

Comment: Thanks. So after launching dalvik, SIM initialization will be done? Is there any document that explain the messages send between SIM and android?

Comment: Dalvik is not directly related to your question in general is when device is finish boot processes (ON_BOOT_COMPLET) ,You shold read about android TelephonyManager, you can start here - http://www.devlper.com/2010/06/using-android-telephonymanager/

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned Dalvik, because I read the boot process and I wanted to know when and how exactly phone initializes SIM. I don't want to develop an app to work with SIM. I just want to find the components that associated in messages send from/to SIM. All components from kernel to application layer.